# Python: How do I arrange a list elements in descending order?

Tags: python, sorting, file-io, python-3.x

If I have this code right here:

```
myfile = open("chess.txt", 'r')

line = myfile.readline().rstrip('\n')
while line != '':
    print(line.rstrip('\n'))
    line = myfile.readline().rstrip('\n')

myfile.close()
```

and it prints out this:

```
1692 The Rickster
2875 Gary Kasparov
1692 Bobby Fisher
1235 Ben Dover
0785 Chuck Roast
1010 Jim Naysium
0834 Baba Wawa
1616 Bruce Lee
0123 K. T. Frog
2000 Socrates
```

What do I need to use to arrange them in order from highest to lowest (numbers)?

the myfile is the list of names and numbers put on a notepad.

Comment: Hi welcome to stack overflow. What have you tried? What hasn't worked? Have you looked at the python list documentation?

Comment: @UpAndAdam: This is not a alphabetical sort; this is a numeric sort in reverse..

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks hadn't noticed that part, removed duplicate and updated my answer with a link to the sort documentation to explain all the options available.

Comment: Bobby Fisher, an amateur angler and 1692-rated patzer, is not to be confused with 2785-rated Grandmaster Bobby Fischer, former world champion.

Answer (score 2):

Read your lines into a list of tuples with the score converted to an integer for ease of sorting numerically, then sort the list:

```
entries = []

with open('chess.txt') as chessfile:
    for line in chessfile:
        score, name = line.strip().split(' ', 1)
        entries.append((int(score), name))

entries.sort(reverse=True)
```

That said, your lines, with the `0`-padded integers at the front, will sort lexicographically as well:

```
with open('chess.txt') as chessfile:
    entries = list(chessfile)

entries.sort(reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This version will work even if the numbers are not 0-padded.

To avoid having to add the key onto the line, use the "key" argument to `sorted`:

```
with open('/tmp/chess.txt') as chessfile:
     print ''.join(sorted(chessfile, reverse=True,
                          key=lambda k: int(k.split()[0])))
```